# Python read string with 'í' and print it

Tags: python, unicode, iso-8859-1

I am reading a json file with python 3.5. In this file it have characters like "í". I would like to print it in that format. How do I make the below code print the character correctly?

```
t = 'í'
print(t)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(t)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xed' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: I can't reproduce this—it prints fine for me. Are you certain that you're using Python 3? Only Python 2 should have that error in this circumstance.

Comment: That's the error you get when you run it using Python 2

Comment: print(sys.version_info) results in 3.6.1

Comment: The json file was opened using: with open('ep_meps_current.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    meps = json.load(fp)

Comment: Now I see that it runs fine on the command line, but not within sublime text 3. Running from the same virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-` as the first or second line of your source file.

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode format.

```
t = u'i'
print(t)
```

You have to add `u` before the character 'i' so that python understands it as unicode.

Comment: In the case that you're typing out literals, that's true. What about the OP's use case, which is reading the strings from file?

Comment: We can specify the encoding during the import of the json file

Comment: python 2 or 3??

Comment: @bigbounty 3.6.1

Comment: @aryamccarthy The json file was opened using: with open('ep_meps_current.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp: meps = json.load(fp)

Comment: Without your file, we cannot test this to verify it, and your question will likely be closed as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(t.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
t = 'í'
print(t.encode("ascii" , "ignore"))
```